# Can't get this AJAX call working in PhoneGap

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

Using PhoneGap, I'm trying to build a basic android app that makes an AJAX call to a PHP API and return some JSON data. The code, in its entirety works on the desktop, but it doesn't seem to work for my Android when I make a build. When I build the app, install it on my device, and load it up, I get blank screen.

Here's the client that I wrote... Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API

            $.support.cors = true;
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://api.example.com/test.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function(data, status) {
                    //data loaded
                    $('#results').append(data[0].about);
                },
                error: function() {
                    //error loading data
                    $('#results').append('No data received.');
                }
            });
            $(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
                $("#msg").append("<li>Error requesting page " + settings.url + "</li>");
            });
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
                $("#msg").append("<li>Request Complete.</li>");
            });
        }
    </script>
    <p id="results"></p>
    <p id="msg"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

I also set the access origins in the config.xml to:

```
<access origin="http://example.com" subdomains="true" /> 
<access origin="*"/>
```

It seems that the AJAX code (and the global AJAX event handlers) is not getting called.

Comment: try adding **http or https** in `<script>` and `<link>` tag

Comment: @turtle that doesn't do it.

Comment: any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have cordova.js included in the right location and available (e.g. by `alert(<some cordova property>);`). Then try if the onDeviceReady is called at all:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
      alert("deviceready");
 },false);
```